# Facebook graph API access for academic projects

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I hope someone from facebook developer team can read this and resolve this in time for the event.
Basically we are students at Carnegie Mellon University participating in Emirates hackathon
emirateshackathon.com
For our proof of concept prototype that we are planning to build requires access to User_likes ,user_books ,user_events permissions for which aren't provided by default.
The problem is we don't have a website set up in place and facebook will not grant our app permission to access these user details.
Useful side note-Facebook is an official partner for the event.

Our facebook App ID is 764055100384482

Is there any clause to provide sandboxed access to all user permissions for academic projects?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you don´t get the permissions approved (which seems to be the case), there is only one more way: You have to add everyone who will use the App at least as Tester in the roles section. Although, without a website/server, there is no way at all. i mean, how do you even want to create a login for the user without any server?